# Up-to-date lineup of WYSIWYG editors?

Tags: 7

I've been browsing through modules at drupal.org, in search for a Drupal7-savvy WYSIWYG editor. I looked into this (horribly outdated) [lineup](http://drupal.org/node/208456). It looks like the only actively maintained editor at this moment is CKEditor. Has anyone come across any other solution? Even if not wrapped into module, perhaps it would be easy to integrate into admin-side.
I'm obviously looking for the least expensive option. Ability to define custom templates and integration with Media module - would be a plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you see so many abandoned projects is that instead of maintaining multiple separate modules for individual packages, work has gone into making those packages compatible with the [WYSIWYG API](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module. By abstracting the editor library from the editing interface, you gain the ability to use different editors for different input formats, and it becomes quite simple to swap one out for another.

According to the project page, WYSIWYG API has direct integration with

- CKEditor
- FCKeditor
- jWysiwyg
- markItUp
- NicEdit
- openWYSIWYG
- TinyMCE
- Whizzywig
- WYMeditor
- YUI editor

as well as a whole host of [useful plugins](http://drupal.org/node/358296).

Comment: Thanks. I really hope for that effort to bring us a fruit. I was somewhat worried that CKEditor can only be used under a paid license, but this is true towards CKFinder module, not the editor itself, which can be run free as OpenSource software.